# Get Data from Python and print it using Java & Thymleaf

Tags: java, python, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I currently working on how to get data back from Python. the scenario is to send data to python script to process it and send the output to java code. the java code should be able to print these data to a html page.

My Python output is a dataframe of about 1.5 million lines.

here my java code

```
 public void addAObjectForm(@RequestParam("Coord1") String Coord1,@RequestParam("Coord2") 
 String Coord2 ,@RequestParam("Coord3") String Coord3, @RequestParam("Coord4")String Coord4,@RequestParam("datedeb") 
 String datedeb,@RequestParam("datefin") String datefin,@RequestParam("datevisua") String datevisua) throws IOException {
//System.out.println(Coord1);
try
{
     String pathPython = "C:/Users/21622/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4/projet1/test1.py";
     String [] cmd = new String[9];
     cmd[0] = "python";
     cmd[1] = pathPython;
     cmd[2] = Coord1;
     cmd[3] = Coord2;
     cmd[4] = Coord3;
     cmd[5] = Coord4;
     cmd[6] = datedeb;
     cmd[7] = datefin;
     cmd[8] = datevisua;
     Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Process p = r.exec(cmd);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     while((s=in.readLine()) != null){
         System.out.println(s);
        // System.out.println(Coord1);
         }
}

catch(Exception e){
}

}
```

and the python code

```
coord1=sys.argv[1] // data got from java ans sys package
coord2=sys.argv[2]
coord3=sys.argv[3]
coord4=sys.argv[4]
cord1=float(coord1)
cord2=float(coord2)
cord3=float(coord3)
cord4=float(coord4)
datedeb=sys.argv[5]
datefin=sys.argv[6]
datevisu=sys.argv[7]
Latitude=pd.read_csv('./latitude.csv')
Longitude=pd.read_csv('./longitude.csv')
Latitude=pd.DataFrame({'Latitude':Latitude})
Longitude=pd.DataFrame({'Longitude':Longitude})
Res=pd.concat([Longitude, Latitude,SM],axis=1) // the result that should be returned to java and displayed in thymleaf page
```

the

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     while((s=in.readLine()) != null){
         System.out.println(s);
        // System.out.println(Coord1);
```

give me nothing. should I add some thing to the python code ?

Can you please give me some tips to help me step forward

thanks in advance

Comment: Does the Java terminate?

Comment: In your Python code, the variable Res needs to be emitted according to a format that's expected by your Java code. As it stands, Res is constructed (in memory) then effectively lost when the Python code terminates. Possibly just print(Res)